# Can application_name be accessed from a trigger?

Tags: postgresql

The PostgreSQL documentation lists a number of [System Information Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) which provide state from the current connection, such as `inet_client_addr()` or `pg_backend_pid()`. I would like to create an audit trail for updates to a table which includes the `application_name`, but there does not seem to be a function for accessing this.

The `application_name` is visible from the `pg_stat_activity` view and is set by clients in the format of

```
username:progname@hostname
```

How can this information be accessed from a trigger?

Comment: Does selecting from the pg_stat_activity view not work? You can filter based on pid to select pid of current query, I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the function `current_setting()`[1], eg:

```
sebastian=# select current_setting('application_name');
 current_setting
-----------------
 psql
(1 row)
```

Testing a new value:

```
sebastian=# set application_name to db_overflow;
SET
sebastian=# select current_setting('application_name');
 current_setting
-----------------
 db_overflow
(1 row)
```

References:

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html